# Why does this print statement using a Python f-string output double parentheses?

Tags: python, python-3.x, parentheses, f-string

In the following code I output the range of values which I can use to index the list `lst`.
However, due to some oddity of Python's format literals the output contains two opening and two closing parentheses instead of one.
I don't see what's wrong with my format string. I just put all expressions which should be substituted in curly braces. The rest should not be substituted.

```
lst = [1,2,3,4,5,6]
print(f"range({-len(lst), len(lst)})")
> range((-6, 6))
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The expression `-len(lst), len(lst)` is a tuple. Usually it's the comma that makes a tuple, not the parentheses. So your output shows the outer parentheses that you explicitly wrote, and the inner parentheses from the tuple. To avoid that, have a separate format for each item you want to print:

```
print(f"range({-len(lst)}, {len(lst)})")
```

Alternatively, you can remove the explicit parentheses:

```
print(f"range{-len(lst), len(lst)}")
```

Comment: Sorry, i should have come to the conclusion on my own. Sometimes one does not see the forest for the trees.

Comment: @pqans. No worries. I strongly suspect that this Q&A will be useful to future readers :)

Answer (score 0):

You should have put the curly brackets individually, not in whole. Like:

```py
print(f"range({-len(lst)}, {len(lst)})")
```

If that doesn't work then I don't know any other solutions.